# Validation required for wiring of a 3 pin illuminated rocker switch

Tags: switches, wiring, mosfet-driver

I'm trying to reproduce a setup for an induction heater. [This is the one I am looking to do](https://www.reddit.com/r/Dynavap/comments/btmvt9/basic_induction_heater_schematic_includes/), but I ended up buying a rocker switch that has an integrated led, and it has 3 pins. Now I did find [a guide to wire this kind of switch](https://www.hunker.com/13414442/how-to-connect-a-lighted-rocker-switch), but I'm not entirely convinced I applied what I learned there to the setup I want to reproduce, since it has to be wired to a mosfet, which is not the case with the guide.

[Here's the (non technical) schematic I made](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Quxf1.jpg). If any one can help me by pointing if either I am right or wrong with the rocker switch, and if I'm wrong... What did I got wrong ?

[image]

Comment: You did use the rocker switch correctly but that momentary switch at output of MOSFET PWM module seems odd. If power is applied to input of the MOSFET PWM module but it only outputs when applied a trigger, then how can triggering it from the output actually turn output on? I believe that momentary switch should be connected to Vin+ of MOSFET PWM module.

Comment: @Leoman12 oh wait, I think you're right, I found an updated schematic of the one I used: https://i.imgur.com/bNvRljn.png. That one should make more sense ?

Comment: @ Jean-Philippe Murray, yes that new schematic is better.

Comment: Thank you @Leoman12 for this validation!

Comment: When editing use Ctrl-M to open the inbuilt schematic editor. It's very intuitive and easy to use. Try it, you'll like it.

Comment: Woa, mindblown ! Thanks for the tip @RussellMcMahon !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You did use the three terminal rocker switch correctly but as mentioned in comments, you should use the updated schematic showing how to properly connect the momentary switch.